# How to make a cursor in a PyQt5 label

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, label

I have a PyQt5 window that has a label with text in it.

The text that appears there is from a python string variable. The string is built by the user clicking on on-screen pushbuttons and then the string is outputted to the window in that label.

As of now I have a backspace button which deletes the last character in the string, but I would also like the user to be able to click on a spot in front of a character in the label, and then be able to delete that character.

So, I would like to know how to do two things.

1. how to get the character location in the string based on the user click
2. I've seen some examples for this, but I'd like to also show a cursor in that spot once the user has clicked there.

I would like to do this with a label widget - not with a text input field.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: With a label you cannot get a 100% reliable cursor position, but there are ways to disable text input in a QLineEdit (most importantly, by overriding `keyPressEvent()`). Why do you specifically need a QLabel?

Comment: @musicamante if I override KeyPressEvent() then no user input can be inputed from the keyboard? if so then as long as I can place a string variable in a QLineEdit then that might work.

Comment: is there a way to disable all keys on the keyboard besides for numbers?

Comment: Is that your only requirement that makes you avoid a QLineEdit?

Comment: I wouldn't say the only requirement, but the other requirements I feel more comfortable that I would find solution online (such as setting the cursor to not appear until clicked amongst other requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a QLabel work like that is hard (QLabel is more complex than it looks).
It *is* possible to show the cursor after clicking, and that's achieved by setting the [`textInteractionFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textInteractionFlags-prop) property:

```
self.label.setTextInteractionFlags(
    QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse | QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByKeyboard)
```

The first flag is to allow handle of mouse events, while the second allows displaying the cursor as soon as the label has focus (for instance, after clicking it).
Unfortunately, this doesn't allow you to get the cursor position (nor to change it); there *are* ways (using QFontMetrics and QTextDocument), but you need a complex implementation in order to make it *really* reliable.

The solution is to use a QLineEdit and override the [`keyPressEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#keyPressEvent), which is the function that is always called on a widget whenever a key press happens (and it has input focus). Considering that number input seems still required, just ensure that the [`event.key()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#key) corresponds to a [`Qt.Key`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Key-enum) enum for numbers, and in that case, call the base implementation.
You can even make it look exactly like a QLabel by properly setting its stylesheet.

```py
class CommandLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    allowedKeys = (
        QtCore.Qt.Key_0, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_1, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_2, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_3, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_4, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_5, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_6, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_7, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_8, 
        QtCore.Qt.Key_9, 
    )
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            CommandLineEdit {
                border: none;
                background: transparent;
            }
        ''')

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in self.allowedKeys:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Then, if you want to set the text programmatically, also based on the cursor, here's a basic usage:

```py
from functools import partial

class CommandTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.commandLineEdit = CommandLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.commandLineEdit)
        keys = (
            'QWERTYUIOP', 
            'ASDFGHJKL', 
            'ZXCVBNM'
        )
        backspaceButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='<-')
        enterButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='Enter')
        self.shiftButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='Shift', checkable=True)
        for row, letters in enumerate(keys):
            rowLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            rowLayout.addStretch()
            layout.addLayout(rowLayout)
            for letter in letters:
                btn = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text=letter)
                rowLayout.addWidget(btn)
                btn.clicked.connect(partial(self.typeLetter, letter))
            rowLayout.addStretch()
            if row == 0:
                rowLayout.addWidget(backspaceButton)
            elif row == 1:
                rowLayout.addWidget(enterButton)
            else:
                rowLayout.addWidget(self.shiftButton)
        spaceLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(spaceLayout)
        spaceLayout.addStretch()
        spaceButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(minimumWidth=200)
        spaceLayout.addWidget(spaceButton)
        spaceLayout.addStretch()

        backspaceButton.clicked.connect(self.commandLineEdit.backspace)
        spaceButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.typeLetter(' '))

    def typeLetter(self, letter):
        text = self.commandLineEdit.text()
        pos = self.commandLineEdit.cursorPosition()
        if not self.shiftButton.isChecked():
            letter = letter.lower()
        self.commandLineEdit.setText(text[:pos] + letter + text[pos:])

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = CommandTest()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you see, you can call [`backspace()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#backspace) in order to clear the last character (or the selection), and in the `typeLetter` function there are all the remaining features you required: getting/setting the text and the cursor position.
For anything else, just study the full [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html).

Comment: I managed to make the QLineEdit look similar to Label, but have been having trouble disabling the keyboard with keyPressOverride. I tried looking up more info on that topic and have been having trouble implementing that into my code. Would you be able to explain the first code snippet that you posted a little more so that I can try and better understand how to implement it into my code?

Comment: The implementation is really simple: if the `key()` of the event (which returns a Qt.Key enum) is included in the `allowedKeys` tuple, then the event is processed as the base QLineEdit would, otherwise it's just *ignored*. I don't know how you implemented your code, we cannot help you further more without any context.

Comment: i figured out what was missing. I needed to add `self.centralwidget.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent` beforehand (where centralwidget is the mainwindow) in order to make the keyPressEvent override

Comment: do you by any chance also know how to disable selecting the text in the QLineEdit? I would like to have a cursor but not allow the user to select the text (make it blue or grey) with the cursor (I found ways to do this in PyQt4 but I've had more trouble with PyQ5)?

Comment: 1. from what you're writing, you're not subclassing, and I believe that's just because you're trying to use a UI created in Designer. If that's so, that brings to the next point, for which... 2. you need subclassing, and the only way to do that if using Designer UIs is by using promoted widgets; do some research on the subject as there are lots of resources about it, even for PyQt.

Comment: Wow. Spot on. Yes, I'm using Qt Designer for my initial GUI (and then editing the code).  I'm going to look into how to promote widgets. Do you know how to disable selecting text in the QLineEdit though?

Comment: There's no direct way to do that, but there are various approaches depending on the requirements, so I suggest you to study the documentation and find *your* appropriate way to do so.

Comment: Regarding what you mentioned about widget promotion. I've spent (literally) two days doing research on widget promotion for PyQt5 and trying to understand it better but I've had lots of trouble with it (I actually came across quite a few post that were by you). In my case, I want to promote the centralwidget but have been having a lot of trouble understanding what to include in the header file field. I'm trying to override the keys on the keyboard for my entire GUI program (hence wanting to promote centralwidget). Any chance you know how I'm able to do that and what to put for the header file?

Comment: @yem that's a completely different topic, so I recommend you to create a separate question for that. In any case consider that completely disabling keyboard events might not be a good idea (and there's the risk that you don't do it properly, with the result that you might still get some events even if you want to, while others that *should* be captured are then not received). When creating the new post please clarify what is the purpose of what you're trying to achieve, as I'm afraid you could be facing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).